# Do I need a transit visa in Heathrow as a Bolivian Citizen?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, lhr

I'm a bolivian citizen currently living in Bolivia until November 6th at which point I will join my family in Norway. The Norwegian visa application has been approved, I hold a Schengen visa (already stamped on my passport) to enter Norway and I am supposed to stop by the authorities having jurisdiction in Norway to get the permanent visa stamped on my passport upon arrival.

I will arrive to the UK via Heathrow and will be in transit for 2 hours before I board my flight to Oslo on the same day.

I also have a 10-year tourist visa to the US. Will I need a visa to pass through the UK? If so, which one?